react-roulette-pro - is there any way to control odds?
I have this component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RoulettePro from 'react-roulette-pro';
import 'react-roulette-pro/dist/index.css';

const prizes = [
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/6Z6Xm9d/good-1.png',
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/T1M05LR/good-2.png',
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/Qbm8cNL/good-3.png',
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/5Tpfs6W/good-4.png',
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/64k8D1c/good-5.png',
    },
];

const winPrizeIndex = 0;

const reproductionArray = (array = [], length = 0) => [
    ...Array(length)
        .fill('_')
        .map(() => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]),
];

const reproducedPrizeList = [
    ...prizes,
    ...reproductionArray(prizes, prizes.length * 3),
    ...prizes,
    ...reproductionArray(prizes, prizes.length),
];

const generateId = () =>
    `${Date.now().toString(36)}-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)}`;

const prizeList = reproducedPrizeList.map((prize) => ({
    ...prize,
    id: typeof crypto.randomUUID === 'function' ? crypto.randomUUID() : generateId(),
}));

const WheelComponent = () => {
    const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

    const prizeIndex = prizes.length * 4 + winPrizeIndex;

    const handleStart = () => {
        setStart((prevState) => !prevState);
    };

    const handlePrizeDefined = () => {
        console.log(' Prize defined! ');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <RoulettePro
                prizes={prizeList}
                prizeIndex={prizeIndex}
                start={start}
                onPrizeDefined={handlePrizeDefined}
            />
            <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default WheelComponent;

That is basically a simple implementation of react roulette pro
But is there a way to make it so a specific item is more rare  than the others?
So I can avoind giving out too many high prises items ?
seems like tampering with the prizeList causes the roulette to not know how  to select prizes anymore, often causing it to not manage lower indexes, causing it to get stuck (or not able to go "back" to a lower index)

This library permits you to choose the index of prizes.
So in taking the given example, you can do a little trick
In your prizes array, add a 'ratio' property, typed as 'integer'
const prizes = [
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/6Z6Xm9d/good-1.png',
        ratio: 1
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/T1M05LR/good-2.png',
        ratio: 5
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/Qbm8cNL/good-3.png',
        ratio: 1
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/5Tpfs6W/good-4.png',
        ratio: 1
    },
    {
        image: 'https://i.ibb.co/64k8D1c/good-5.png',
        ratio: 1
    },
];

With this, in following the example, you can simulate a broken dice.
const API = {
  getPrizeIndex: async () => {
    const extendedPrizes = prizes.reduce(
      (o, a, i) => [
        ...o,
        ...new Array(a.ratio)
          .fill({
            ...o,
            count: (o[o.length - 1]?.count || 0) + a.ratio,
            index: i,
          })
          .map((j) => ({ ...j, rand: Math.random() })),
      ],
      [],
    );

    extendedPrizes.sort((a, b) => (a.rand < b.rand ? -1 : 1));

    const randomPrizeIndex = getRandomIntInRange(0, extendedPrizes.length - 1);

    const randomPrizeIndexOffset = prizes.length * 4;

    const { index } = extendedPrizes[randomPrizeIndex];

    return index + randomPrizeIndexOffset;
  },
};
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!spinning || !prizeList.length) {
          return;
        }
    
        const prepare = async () => {
          const newPrizeIndex = await API.getPrizeIndex();
          setPrizeIndex(newPrizeIndex);
          setStart(false);
    
          const { id } = prizeList[newPrizeIndex];
    
          Toast.fire({ icon: 'info', title: `Must win id - ${id}` });
        };
    
        prepare();
      }, [spinning, prizeList]);

